# Direct share is not working with my app. ChooserTargetService is not called

Tags: android, android-sharing

I referred sample application code (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-DirectShare) and I added ChooserTargetService to my application

```
public class ShareChooserTargetService extends ChooserTargetService {

@Override
public List<ChooserTarget> onGetChooserTargets(ComponentName targetActivityName,
                                               IntentFilter matchedFilter) {

    Log.d("ShareChooserTargetService", "onGetChooserTargets: ");

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            ShareActivity.class.getCanonicalName());

    ArrayList<ChooserTarget> targets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User user : Users.getAll()) {
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("user_id", user.id);
        targets.add(new ChooserTarget(
                user.name,
                Icon.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_user),
                componentName,
                extras));
    }
    return targets;
}
```

In Manifest file I added these lines:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.ShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
            android:value=".ShareChooserTargetService" />
    </activity>

<service
        android:name=".ShareChooserTargetService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

But ShareChooserTargetService is not called, log isn't printed. I run sample application in my phone and it works perfectly but these code in my app isn't working. I am unable to find what is the issue. Can anyone help please?

Comment: This issue is solved by putting full name of ShareChooserTargetService in manifest file.